# Excel VBA Check between values in a InStr function

Tags: excel, vba

**My situation**

My main reason why i made this code is to check if a ip address is a intern or extern connection.

A cell in my data sheet, does not only contain a IP address value but can also contain other type of text. F.e. :

"BE-ABCDDD-DDS 172.16.23.3"

**My problem**

I want to check if a cell contains a ip address of "172.16" between "172.31"
In the example above it would return a value true/Intern. If the cell conaints a value of
"172.32" would return false/extern.

**this is my code:**

```
For Each source In Range("E6", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))      
    If (InStr(source, "-10.") <> 0 Or InStr(source, "-192.168.") <> 0 Or InStr(source, "-  172.") <> 0) And InStr(source.Offset(0, 22).Value, "Extern") = 0 Then
source.Offset(0, 22) = "Intern"
    End If
Next source
```

As you can see in my code, it only checks on "172." at the moment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your questions seems not clear to me. Can you rephrase??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could/should break out that test into its own function.  Here's an example just parsing the string.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A5").Cells
        If IsInternal(rCell.Value) Then
            Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Function IsInternal(sIpAdd As String) As Boolean

    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Dim lIpStart As Long
    Dim lSecQuad As Long

    Const sIPSTART As String = "172."
    Const lMIN As Long = 16
    Const lMAX As Long = 31

    'Default to false unless we explictly set it to true
    bReturn = False

    'See if 172. exists in the string
    lIpStart = InStr(1, sIpAdd, sIPSTART)

    'If 172. exists
    If lIpStart > 0 Then
        'Parse out the second quadrant
        lSecQuad = Val(Mid(sIpAdd, lIpStart + Len(sIPSTART), 2))

        'See if the second quadrant is in range
        'and set to true if so
        bReturn = lSecQuad >= lMIN And lSecQuad <= lMAX
    End If

    IsInternal = bReturn

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend a regular expression for this. If you are using VBA you can reference the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library in your VBA project.

Once you have that referenced, you could using a regular expression to search the string for a  given matching pattern. Heres an example VBScript regex friendly expression for an 'possibly-valid-IP-string': \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}

That will match a string that has a sequence of 4, 1-3 digit numbers, with periods in it, such as 127.0.0.1 but also possibly 955.556.234.234. So once you have a string that matches, I would validate the ip components in code before you consider the IP 'valid'. Once you have a valid IP it should be a snap to check for your condition.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your quick answer.Im realy new to VBA, i understand what you mean, but i can't implement it. I think i need a step by step approach